# AWS Glue read null value for default set up in database, how to avoid it?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have 2 tables with almost the same structure, one thing is that the origin database use `mySQL` while destination database use `PostgreSQL`

The origin database has a column with this set up (mySQL)

```
`used_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
```

The destination database has this set up for the same column (postgreSQL)

```
used_time integer default 1 not null,
```

When I run AWS Glue, I got this error:

```
An error occurred while calling o132.pyWriteDynamicFrame. ERROR: null value in column "used_time" violates not-null constraint
```

The column `used_time` of the origin database (mySQL) was left empty while inputing data and was obviously set default value as 1.

But it seems that AWS glue reads it as null. That is the reason why I cannot pass data to the destination database (postgreSQL).

I tried to delete the `NOT NULL` constraint of the destination database (postgreSQL) and it works but the value of column `used_time` is all `null`

Any way to get out of this problem ? Please help.

For your information about the script

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "venus staging", table_name = "venus_containers", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")

Transform0 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource0, mappings = [("flight", "string", "flight", "string"), ("permanent_label", "string", "permanent_label", "string"), ("cargo_id", "string", "cargo_id", "string"), ("created_at", "timestamp", "created_at", "timestamp"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("seal_actual_weight", "int", "seal_actual_weight", "int"), ("total_packages", "int", "total_packages", "int"), ("total_valid_packages", "int", "total_valid_packages", "int"), ("updated_at", "timestamp", "updated_at", "timestamp"), ("unseal_actual_weight", "int", "unseal_actual_weight", "int"), ("used_time", "int", "used_time", "int"), ("creator_id", "string", "creator_id", "string"), ("updater_id", "string", "updater_id", "string"), ("id", "string", "id", "string"), ("parent_container_id", "string", "parent_container_id", "string"), ("is_closed", "boolean", "is_closed", "short"), ("status", "string", "status", "string"), ("bracket_id", "string", "bracket_id", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform0")

DataSink0 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = Transform0, database = "dwh venus staging", table_name = "dwh_venus_containers", transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
job.commit()
```

Here is how it mapping as you notice
("used_time", "int", "used_time", "int")

Comment: Can you provide the code that reads from MySQL?

Comment: @RobertKossendey, I already include the script

Comment: Can you run print(DataSource0.schema()) and tell me what the data type of used_time is?

Comment: from the `Crawler` its `int` mate, since it is quite a simple job, I work mainly on Aws Glue website, without do anything relating to code, but I am open to do coding if it necessary

Comment: I know that the crawler displays int, but Glue provides choices in the background. Sometimes you have to call resolveChoice for that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html

Comment: the link is helpful, I will try to fix it on that way

Comment: Okay, if it worked, I will sum up the solution in an answer